# Canvas scaling for GameObjects in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have searched online for the problem, and they always result in code. I am trying to do scaling of GameObjects just like I would an Image. Let me explain, here is an Image of me manipulating an image with a canvas:

[image]

Now here is an image of my paddle in inspector

[image]

The paddle has an image, a ridged body, box collider, etc. But I want the paddle to be able to be scaled like the background image gets scaled. **Is there a way I can put the paddle in the canvas so that the box collider, image, etc scales.** Any help with this is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't hink there is a simple solution to your problem, because the elements you want don't necessarily have a width and height that means something in a RectTransform.

For instance, your box collider is a 3D shape (speaking of this, you might want to use a BoxCollider2D)
Anyway, Only the Unity UI components react to RectTransforms. Colliders aren't UI elements. All the components you talk about react differently:

- **Image** is a 2d ui component with a width and height. It will scale in your canevas
- **BoxCollider** isn't a UI element. it won't scale, but you can do it programmatically by copying the values of transform.Rect inside collider.Size. I am pretty sure you can find several examples of that on the internet
- **Paddle** is your own component, so of course it will only do what you programmed it to do. I don't see what you mean by "put the paddle in the canvas". Your paddle isn't a graphic element. It doesn't have a width and height. The Image component however will have a width since it is a UI component